# Add Contract Line to Contract CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I hope somone can help me further, as I'm really much stuck here. Im trying to add a contract line to my contract entity from a post-creat plugin. My code:

```cs
Guid c_Id = (Guid)entity.Attributes["contractid"];
DateTime start = (DateTime)entity["activeon"];
DateTime end = (DateTime)entity["expireson"];
Money money = new Money();
money.Value = 0;


//Set Instance for Contract Line 
Entity ContractLine = new Entity();
ContractLine.LogicalName = "contractdetail";

//Create Contract Line for the Contract
ContractLine["title"] = "PLUGIN FIRED";
ContractLine["activeon"] = start;
ContractLine["expireson"] = end;
ContractLine["totalallotments"] = 1;
//ContractLine["customerid"] = entity["customerid"];  
//ContractLine["productid"] = entity["productid"];
ContractLine["price"] = money;
ContractLine["contractid"] = c_Id;

service.Create(ContractLine);
```

For some reason I get the error that "Attribute: contractid cannot be set to NULL" which really stragnge because it actually does get the GUID for the contractid, as I checkd it on another field on another entity. I would really much appreciate if somone can help me out here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should `ContractLine["contractid"]` = c_Id; be `ContractLine["contractid"] = new EntityReference("contract", c_Id);`?

Also should c_Id be an EntityReference instead of a GUID?

Comment: Thank you very much Boone, Appreciate it soo much worked for me. I had to change it to ContractLine["contractid"] = new EntityReference("contract", c_Id).

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you have another plugin that is firing as a result of yours that is throwing the exception.  That always seems to bite me.  Try disabling all other plugins except for the one you're working on...

Comment: Hi Daryl, I'm working on a dev environment, that is not the case. But it is really strange because it actaully gets the contractId but when I set it for the ContractLine["contractid"] I get this error.

Comment: So if you debug it, the exception is getting thrown on this line: ContractLine["contractid"] = c_Id; or is it getting thrown during the create?

Comment: Hi Daryl, thank for your effore the answer is show below, I had to set it like this ContractLine["contractid"] = new EntityReference("contract", c_Id); Appreicate your reply again.

Comment: No prob.  I generated and use the early bound objects instead of the plain Entity Object, which would catch that sort of error at compile time, rather than run time.